# jQuery IE9: Unable to get value of the property 'val': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I get this error in IE9, pointing to the line `return self.subQuantity.val();` in the snippet below. What could cause this?

I should add this works perfectly in FF.

Partial function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    plan = (function() {
        var plan = {
            subQuantity: $('.downgrade .count'),
...

init: function(productCatalog) {
                this.prod = productCatalog;
                this.reset();
                self = this;

                this.fetchButton.bind('click', function(e) {
                    self.fetchScenarii();
                    return false;
                }).filter(function() {
                    return self.subQuantity.val();
                })
            }
```

HTML

```
<div class="downgrade">
...
<input type="count" name="count" />
...
</div>
```

Comment: What is `subQuantity`?  A variable, a text field?

Comment: What is prodCat?  the function takes the parameter productCatalog.

Comment: @blake305 subQuantity should now be clear, sorry for the mistake

Comment: @scott.korin prodCat should now be clear, I'd wrongly renamed some elements for posting

Comment: How is `init` getting called?  What does `self` look like inside the filter callback?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>            self = this;
> ```

Is the mistake. You're writing to the [global `self` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.self) (a reference back to `window`) here - which is non-writable  in IE. Add a [`var` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

```
            var self = this;
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

it's return as undefined value so what ever you try to make it like val or length will keep give you the same Error Dialog 
I was facing the Same problem 
The Solution for this 
you need to check if the value is undefined or no before you call any method 
here how I fixed it

```
         if (typeof $("#<%=hdnSupplierDialog.ClientID%>").val() === "undefined")
                return;
```

I just prevent the Code to be called in case the value is undefined 
I wish it works for you :)

Comment: It's not the problem here that `.val()` returns undefind!

Comment: I was using             

$("#<%=hdnSupplierDialog.ClientID%>").val().split(',')
SO I was facing this Issue for me It's working after I prevent it to go there in case of undefind

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
return self.subQuantity.val();
```

to

```
return self.subQuantity.attr("value");
```

Comment: Unable to get value of the property 'attr': object is null or undefined.

Comment: @stef please post html code for the classes `.downgrade .count`

Comment: done, it's just a simple div with inside a form that has one input field.

Comment: @stef are you trying to get the value of the input box?  the value the user typed?