# How come this != self when I declare this = self?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add declare a variable for this, so I can use it inside a http-request-callback:

It doesn't work though, self becomes the window-object, rather than "this".

```
mycompany.getData(mycompany.save.bind(mycompany))

company.prototype.getData = function(callback){
    console.log(this)//outputs the object company
    self = this;
    console.log(this)//outputs the object company
    console.log(self)//outputs the window object
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            ...
            callback
    })
}
```

Comment: can you try and reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: Where are you declaring `self`?

Comment: `var self = this;`?

Comment: I'd like to see a reproduction of this as well. In addition, you don't need to bind(mycompany) when you are calling mycompany.save() - it's redundant.

Comment: This works fine for me in FF - [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UfedM/)

Comment: couldn't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/KLDk5/

Comment: You don't have `var` specified.  `self = this` sets the global variable `self`.

Comment: Could be related to Chrome's delayed `console.log` evaluations.

Comment: Also, it would appear your function is also being called in global context.  The keyword `this` will be window when no context is available to ensure `this` is always something.  If you have no context, it's as if you called your function like `mycompany.getData.call(null, mycompany.save.bind(mycompany));`.  That or you passed `getData` to another function as a callback...?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery IE9: Unable to get value of the property 'val': object is null or undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790348/jquery-ie9-unable-to-get-value-of-the-property-val-object-is-null-or-undefin)

Comment: Hang on.  You are calling `getData` on `mycompany` but creating a function `getData` on `company`??

Comment: @Craig `mycompany` is most probably an instance of `company`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `self` global variable refers to [`window.self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self)
Try to change the code:

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: Or better yet, choose another name than self.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locally cast certain variables, `$` is a good convention:

```
function() {
    var $this = this;

    console.log($this);
}
```

Comment: `$` mostly denotes (jQuery) wrapper objects so I would avoid that.

Comment: If using JQuery.  However, I did say it is a good convention, not the only.  Underscores also denote `private`ness.  You can use these also: `var _this = this;`.  The possibilities are endless.